# Navigation template

Tags: navigation

I would like to edit my navigation template.

I found a way to do this, by editing `wp-includes/link-template.php`

Replaced this :

```
function _navigation_markup( $links, $class = 'posts-navigation', $screen_reader_text = '' ) {
if ( empty( $screen_reader_text ) ) {
    $screen_reader_text = __( 'Posts navigation' );
}

$template = '
<nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
    <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
    <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
</nav>';
```

With this :

```
function _navigation_markup( $links, $class = 'posts-navigation', $screen_reader_text = '' ) {
if ( empty( $screen_reader_text ) ) {
    $screen_reader_text = __( 'Posts navigation' );
}

$template = '
<footer>
    <nav id="nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">%3$s</nav>
</footer>';
```

It worked, but I would like to edit the theme rather than the Wordpress core.

Tryed to edit `functions.php` with this :

```
function custom_navigation_markup( $links, $class = 'posts-navigation', $screen_reader_text = '' ) {
if ( empty( $screen_reader_text ) ) {
    $screen_reader_text = __( 'Posts navigation' );
}

$template = '
<footer>
    <nav id="nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">%3$s</nav>
</footer>';
```

But it returned a 500 error. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to add this in `functions.php` :

```
add_filter('navigation_markup_template', 'my_navigation_template', 10, 2 );
function my_navigation_template( $template, $class ){

    return 
    '<footer>
        <nav id="nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">%3$s</nav>
    </footer>';
}
```

Source : http://wp-kama.ru/function/_navigation_markup